# What is the datatype for image when doing a design class diagram?

Tags: types, uml

I have to make a UML Design class diagram of a sale. When creating the classes, one of the classes (Product) has an image of the item as one of its properties. I have to indicate visibility, the property and the datatype. Which datatype do I use for the image? For example I have properties like :

- productId : int
- productName : string
- productPrice : decimal
- productImage : ????

Answer (score 4):

UML does not prescribe which **PrimitiveTypes** or **DataTypes** you need to use.
It does define a set of reusable Primitive Types, but this is mainly used in the definition of meta-models.

You should define your own **PrimitiveTypes** and **DataTypes** that are to be used in your model.

In this case it seems like the best option would be to create a **DataType** `Image`.
This could look something like this, depending on your needs:

[image]

Comment: I guess you chipped in because of https://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,44802.0.html

Comment: @qwerty_so not really, but that was indeed a very interesting discussion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no primitive type for an image, you can create your own class *Image* for that.

Out of that warning the primitives types names you use are not the predefined ones, probably you want in order :

- Integer
- String
- Real

(c.f. chapter 21 of [formal 2017/12/05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) )

Comment: These are the primitive types used in the metamodel of UML, but you can create as many primitives in your model as you want/need. A model should not only use these primitive types.

Comment: the probability the OP wants to use predefined primitive type is very high, it seems my sentence is not clear, I modify it

Comment: I also use the predefined primitive types as much as possible (Integer instead of int), _except_ if the attributes must have a one-on-one relationship with technical attributes; in that case, I use the technical data types, as defined by the target programming language or by the target DBMS.